# How can i write separate lines with open(namefile.txt, w) in python?

Tags: python

i don't know how to separate lines in a text file in python. What i mean is that i want to write a text file with some values that the user can put in input (and this is the easy part) but i also want that every value that the user put in input is properly separate in the txt file (so basically on different lines)
This is the code that i wrote:

```
   file= open("txt.txt", "w")
   Value1 = input("value1: ")
   Value2 = input("value2: ")
   file.write(Value1)
   file.write(Value2)

   file.close()
```

When i check the txt.txt file the values are on the same line... anyone knows what i can do to have Value1 and Value2 on different lines?

Comment: yes, write a newline character after each write.